# My SQL function to change user_name

Tags: query, mysql

My wordPress database was hacked and all users_names were changed to the same thing. I'd like to write a mySql query to replace all usernames that = "x" to the user_nicename. I'm unsure how to do this - any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This should be working:

Be sure that your DB prefix is "wp_"

```
Update wp_users set wp_users.user_login=wp_users.user_nicename where wp_users.user_login="x"
```

Answer (score 0):

To update the **Nickname** use:

```sql
UPDATE wp_users SET user_nicename = 'new_nick_name' WHERE user_nicename = 'x';
```